# SignUp authentication with firebase using redux-thunk

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

I am trying to signup/adding a user in firebase using redux-thunk. I am trying to add user's email id and password . On submit  I am triggering my submithandler in which I am dispatching a action 'auth' And my action's code is:-

```
`export const SIGNUP ='SIGNUP';

  export const signup = (email, password ) =>{
   return async dispatch =>{
   let response;
   try{
    response = await fetch('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[My-API- 
    Key]',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
            returnSecureToken: true
          })
        });
      console.log(response)
      } catch(e){
       console.log(e);
     }
    // if(!response.ok){
    //     throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    // }
      const resData = await response.json();
       console.log(resData);
       dispatch({type: SIGNUP});
  
      }
    };`
```

When consoling the error
`Object { "error": Object { "code": 400, "errors": Array [ Object { "domain": "global", "message": "INVALID_EMAIL", "reason": "invalid", }, ], "message": "INVALID_EMAIL", }, }`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It says that the problem is an invalid email.  Are you sure that the email address you are  trying with is formatted correctly?

Comment: Yes, I tried my original email-id but didn't work same issue.